# Why does Ctrl+\ (backslash) not kill the process any more?

Tags: process

For a while, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> worked like a charm. Now, it does not kill the process. In fact it does nothing.

An example how it does NOT work:

```
adi@ebi:~ $ sleep 10
^C

[exited with 130]
adi@ebi:~ $ sleep 10
^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\ 
adi@ebi:~ $
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> stops sleep as usual, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> does not, but it should, right?

Comment: I think you could try `xev` for debugging keystrokes.

Comment: Turned out to be a vte bug, which is closed now:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748520

Answer (score 7):

You can list your terminal settings by executing

```
stty -a
```

It will print out your hotkeys, where "^" stands fro <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, e.g mine is:

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O;
```

Check `man stty` to see which special character does what e.g:

```
quit CHAR
          CHAR will send a quit signal
```

So "*quit = ^\*" in my output means that if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> it will send a quit signal (**SIGQUIT**) to the process. If your `stty -a` output is different, then you can set it with

```
stty quit ^\
```

or if you want e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for the SIGQUIT signal use

```
stty quit ^k
```

But note that every signal except the **SIGKILL** can be caught by the receiving process so the process can ignore it if it's developer decided to do so. And also I think that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (SIGINT) is better then using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (SIGQUIT), because the default action for both signal is to end the process but in case of SIGQUIT a coredump should also be made, which I think is usually not wanted.

Answer (score 6):

What <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> does is send `SIGQUIT` to the foreground process. Some developers want to use SIG* events in a way that the user might not expect or is accustomed to. You didn't mention the program, but lets see my case with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> and `mplayer`:

```
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
A:   1.7 (01.7) of 0.0 (unknown)  0.4% 
// here I press Ctrl + \

MPlayer interrupted by signal 3 in module: play_audio
A:   1.0 (00.9) of 0.0 (unknown)  0.4% 

Exiting... (Quit)
```

As you see, mplayer catch the signal, but don't exit immediately. If I had used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it would say *"MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: play_audio"*. What I'm trying to explain is that each program can interpret the signals the way they like, without caring for what it is supposed to do. You must review the documentation. Also, remember that `SIGKILL` or `9` should be resorted as last resource. You must check that the keystrokes are also sent to the process, the keymap is correct and your keyboard is connected.

Comment: Please see the example I added. That should explain what I'm missing.

Comment: @agroszer you miss nothing... I'm guessing but in my case `sleep 10 ^\Quit` exits immediately the same with Ctrl + C. So, it's possible a performance problem.