# How do I go back to the bottom of history after pressing up in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

If I scroll way up or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> search and go way up in the history, how to get back down to the clear line? I know I can clear with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>, but that modifies them. Is there an official way beside <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to reset the shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two "official" options (from [8.4 *Bindable Readline Commands* in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands)):

> `abort (C-g)`
>
> Abort the current editing command and ring the terminal’s bell (subject to the setting of `bell-style`).
>
> `end-of-history (M->)`
>
> Move to the end of the input history, i.e., the line currently being entered.

`M->` can be entered by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>></kbd>, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>></kbd>.

Notes:

- `abort` is to be used while in the history search mode.
- `end-of-history`, on the other hand, should be used after selecting a command from the history search mode (by, e.g, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or an arrow key).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Works a treat! Well the move to end-of-history does. The C-g doesnt but that could be because of an overriding key shortcut in Kubuntu. Konsole has a few of those (C-k). Another handy key combo is C-d to 'exit', often just exits a process and leaves you in the shell, and C-\ will kill many rogue processes and 'dump' (to somewhere). Thanks for the reference doc.

Comment: @alchemy Ctrl-D typically sends an EOF indicator, and Ctrl-\ sends sigquit (those are typically managed by [the line discipline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194146/2072269). You can see these settings using `stty -a` (e.g., https://askubuntu.com/a/385905/158442)

Comment: Ah, you're right about C-d being EOF, which is basically what happens when you press enter in "icanon" mode (if I understand https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/346155). Modern terminals have their own more complex "line editors" and so C-d is a great key to replace. I use it for "intr" interupt so that I can have C-c as copy and C-x as paste. Interesting though that "icanon" mode looks like C-u used to clear the entire line instead of using C-e,C-u combo.